# De onde vem a expressão "escovar bits", e qual o equivalente em inglês?

Tags: terminologia

"Escovar bits" é uma expressão que significa, entre outros, "se preocupar com detalhes de baixo nível", como otimizações excessivas e/ou desnecessárias.

A expressão equivalente em inglês ("bit brushing") não parece existir ou ser muito usada.

De onde veio essa expressão, e como traduzi-la de modo conciso em inglês?

Comment: Não é um assunto essencialmente técnico, apesar de usarmos o termo. É mais linguística. Pergunte no http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/. O significado é quem programa em baixo nível, quem gosta de fazer as coisas de forma mais concreta, mais perto do hardware, se preocupa com todos os detalhes. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escovador_de_bit

Comment: A expressão em inglês seria *bit crushing*. Mas não sei se essa pergunta é on-topic aqui, talvez a parte sobre a origem seja mais adequada no http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/ mesmo.

Comment: O termo _bit crushing_ me soa familiar para manipulações de bits em geral, mas estou tendo dificuldade em encontrá-lo sendo usado fora do contexto de um [efeito musical específico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcrusher).

Comment: @Piovezan É verdade, melhor usar as sugestões da sua resposta.

Comment: Pena que o Google NGRAM não cobre português. Entretando, esta é a referência mais antiga para um termo relacionado: '"O Campeão de vendas, até agora, é o livro Hardware Curso Completo, de Gabriel Torres. Daqueles que ficam em pé sozinhos, o livro ensina a montar e desmontar computadores, no melhor estilo "escovador de bits". - Zero Hora, 11 de novembro de 1998'

Answer (score 13):

*Bit bashing* ou *bit twiddling*. Também *bit diddling*.

Algumas fontes:

- https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/bit%20bashing
- http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/bit-bashing.html

A origem de termo em inglês *bit twiddling* vem dos hardwares antigos de computação em que o programador ficava girando controles para manipular os dados.

Tirado de:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation
- http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bit-bashing

Veja também:

- [The Project Gutenberg eBook of The New Hacker's Dictionary version 4.2.2, by various editors](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/3008/3008-h/3008-h.htm)

---

#### Escovar bits:

[Aqui](http://www.intercom.org.br/papers/nacionais/2003/www/pdf/2003_np08_schwingel.pdf) há uma citação dizendo que a definição original de *hacker* significava "escovador de bits" ou alguém que adorava programar.

> Então – pô –, tu és um *hacker* do movimento. Não no sentido lá da
> origem da palavra de “escovador de bit”, alguém que adora programar.
> Mas é um *hacker*, um integrante do movimento.

*(TEZA, 2000) Mario Teza, integrante da CSL (Comunidade do Software Livre) e um dos responsáveis pelo Movimento Software Livre RS - Rio Grande do Sul.*

##### Atualizado em 13/10/2023:

Explicação retirada de [https://www.ime.usp.br/~song/song2019.pdf](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Esong/song2019.pdf) (pág. do Prof. Dr. Siang Wun Song):

> Na década dos anos 60 algumas universidades [brasileiras] começaram a
> receber os primeiros computadores.
>
> Burroughs B-205 em 1960 na PUC-Rio (1.600 válvulas)
>
> IBM 1620 em 1962 na USP (transistorizado)
>
> IBM 1130 em 1965 na PUC-Rio
>
> IBM 1130 em 1967 na UFRGS
>
> IBM 1130 em 1968 na Unicamp
>
> IBM 1130 em 1968 na UFCG
>
> A chegada de um computador na USP gerou muito
> interesse e atraiu professores e estudantes.
> Nos primeiros computadores da USP (IBM 1620 e depois
> B-3500), pudemos ver o computador literalmente **escovar
> os bits**.
>
> Como? Entrada ao computador era feita por cartões
> perfurados. Para ler um cartão, os buracos de cada coluna
> (codificando um caráter ASCII) passavam por baixo de
> **escovas de aço** que literalmente *escovavam os bits*.

**Cartão perfurado:**

[image: Cartão perfurado com furos em formato retangular]

**Detalhe do leitor/escritor de cartões perfurados [IBM 1402](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_1402)**, com as extremidades das escovas de aço visíveis e uma etiqueta escrita *brushes* ("escovas"):

[image: Detalhe de leitor/escritor de cartões perfurados IBM 1402]

*Fonte das imagens:* Wikipedia, a partir de [song2019.pdf](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Esong/song2019.pdf)

**Escovas em destaque:**

[[image: Grupos de cerdas metálicas destacadas com contorno em vermelho]

Comment: 01000101 01110011 01100011 01101111 01110110 01100001 01101110 01100100 01101111 00100000 01100010 01101001 01110100 01110011